# jQuery hide others and show active class with #id after URL to apply history.back function for last viewed id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that can view 1st id on page loading at the first time and show hide by clicking the main 3 tabs. But I can't get the tab id (`#tab1` or `#tab2` or `#tab3`) after the URL.

I need to apply the `history.back` function for the last viewed tab when I return back to this page from another page. I can't understand how to insert `a[href$=` inside the code if it is the missing part.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //When page loads...
  $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
  //On Click Event
  $("ul.tabs li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
  });
  if (document.location.hash != '') {
    //get the index from URL hash
    var tabName = window.location.hash;
    $(tabName).show(); //Show tab from url hash
    var tabNumber = tabName.substr(4, 1); //shorten #tab2 to just last digit "2"
    $("ul.tabs li:nth-child(tabNumber)").addClass("active").show();
  } else {

    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#tab1" class="active">house</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">vehicle</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">animal</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab_content" id="tab1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1" class="active">all</a></li>
    <li><a href="#house1">house1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#house2">house2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#house3">house3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab_content" id="tab2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab2" class="active">all</a></li>
    <li><a href="#vehicle1">vehicle1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#vehicle2">vehicle2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#vehicle3">vehicle3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab_content" id="tab3">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab3" class="active">all</a></li>
    <li><a href="#animal1">animal1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#animal2">animal2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#animal3">animal3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

trigger click it will be better

- Make change tab as a function
- run the function when document is ready and run it when change the history .. OR when `$(window).on('popstate')`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //When page loads...
  $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
  //On Click Event
  $("ul.tabs li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
  }); 
  
  // run the function 
  ChangeTab();
  
  
  // on back or forward 
  $(window).on('popstate' , function(){
    ChangeTab();
  });
  
});



function ChangeTab(){
  if (document.location.hash !== '') {
     //get the index from URL hash
     var tabName = window.location.hash;
     $('a[href="' + tabName + '"]').closest('li').click();
  } else {
     $('a[href="#tab1"]').closest('li').click();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Yousef. But it does not give the #tabid end of the URL. Still I can't fix. I have some other pages to link every li tab inside tab_content. some of them are same location. ex: vehicle1 heading to vehicle&house.html and house2 heading to the same vehicle&house.html. but I need to put a back button inside every page. If I go to vehicle&house.html from the house2 tab I need to return to the same house2 tab.